# "While": como puedo "print" los valores de while en horizontal separados por una ","?

Tags: python, while

Me gustaria poder imprimir los valores que me arroje:

```
c=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
a=0
while(a<=c):
    print(a)
    a+=2
```

en vez de uno en cada línea:

> >>> Ingrese un numero:
>   9
>   0
>   2
>   4
>   6
>   8
>   .

que aparezca de esta forma:

> 0,2,4,6,8

Answer (score 2):

Si usas Python 3.x basta con especificar el argumento  `end` de la función `print` adecuadamente:

```
c=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
a=0
while(a<=c):
    print(a, end=',')
    a+=2
```

Si usas Python 2.x usando tu código puedes hacer:

```
c=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
a=0
while(a<=c):
    print str(a)+',', 
    a+=2
```

Salida (con `9` de entrada):

> 0,2,4,6,8,

Si deseas eliminar la última coma puedes hacer cualquiera de los siguientes métodos:

**Es más simple, eficiente y mas pythónico usar un `for` con `range` o directamente `range` para hacer algo así**. Esto es válido si usas Python 3.x directamente ó 2.x pero importando `print` de `__future__`:

```
c=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
print(*range(0,c+1,2), sep=',')
```

Salida (con `9` de entrada):

> 0,2,4,6,8

Otra opción es usar variables intermedias (cadenas o listas), generadores y el método `join` de las cadenas. Todo lo que hay a continuación es válido para Python 2 y 3:

- Usando `while`, lista auxiliar y `join` (muy ineficiente):

  ```
  c=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
  aux=[] 
  a=0
  while(a<=c):
      aux.append(str(a))
      a+=2
  print(','.join(aux))
  ```
- Usar una variable auxiliar de tipo `str` en vez de una lista (parecido al anterior):

  ```
  c=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
  aux='' 
  a=0
  while(a<=c):
      aux+=str(a)+','
      a+=2
  print(aux[:-1])
  ```
- Usando `for`, lista auxiliar y `join`:

  ```
  c=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
  aux=[] 
  for a in range(0,c+1,2):
      aux.append(str(a))
  print(','.join(aux))
  ```
- Usando generador y `join`(más eficiente):

  ```
  c=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
  print(','.join(str(n)for n in range(0,c+1,2)))
  ```

Comment: `range(0,c,2)` no debiera ser `range(0,c+1,2)`?

Comment: Si tienes toda la razón Patricio, justo lo estaba corrigiendo cuando lo has comentado. Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, bastante completa.

Answer (score 0):

Hablando en Python 2.7:  Una posible solución la obtendríamos mediante un string al cual le vamos agregando, en cada pasada por el ciclo while, el numero obtenido y una coma. Al salir del ciclo tendremos una coma que nos sobrara al final sin embargo en python es relativamente fácil eliminar elementos que se encuentren al termino del string.

Te dejo una posible solución:

```
c=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
a=0
numeros = "" #String que contendra los numeros
while(a<=c):
    numeros = numeros + str(a) + "," #agregamos al string el numeros y una coma
    a+=2

numeros = numeros[:-1] #Eliminamos la coma que nos sobra
print numeros #Mostramos por pantalla la salida
```

Otra posible solución puede ser la siguiente: Ir guardando cada numero en un arreglo pero al momento de agregarlos los transformaremos a string. Cuando el ciclo while haya concluido solo bastara unir nuestros números, esto lo realizamos gracias al método join.

Join: 
El método join () devuelve una cadena en la que los elementos string de la secuencia han sido unidos por str separador.

En Codigo:

```
c=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
numeros = [] #arreglo que contendra los numeros
a=0
while(a<=c):
    numeros.append(str(a)) #Agregamos los numeros a nuestro arreglo pero estos los transformamos a  string
    a+=2

salida = ",".join(numeros) #Juntamos todos los numeros y los separamos por una coma
print salida
```

En fin se puede realizar de diversas maneras, hasta donde llegue tu imaginación.
Saludos, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue de mucha ayuda <3